# Call an image address that is stored in a MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to complete an img tag src using a filename stored in a mysql database.

At the moment I have to load two images from this one MySQL query (They are chosen at random) moving forward however I will likely need to do more.

This is my current query:

```
    // Get random 2
$query="SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $images[] = (object) $row;
}
```

My connection documentation is stored in a separate file and called earlier in the process (This has worked for other functions so don't think the issue is there)

I then try to insert the image address later on like this:

```
<img src="images/<?=$images[0]->filename?>"  style="width:100%">
<img src="images/<?=$images[1]->filename?>"  style="width:100%">
```

I've been staring at this and trying stuff for the best part of an hour so it's likely it's either an obvious and stupid problem or I've gone completely off track!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get an error or an incorrect path to the images? If you look at the rendered HTML what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_object()`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $images[] = $row;
}
```

But, that inline PHP does not look reliable at all. You will want to do it like this.

```
<img src="images/<?php echo $images[0]["filename"]; ?>" style="width:100%" />
<img src="images/<?php echo $images[1]["filename"]; ?>" style="width:100%" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The rendered HTML is now throwing up this error


 `<img src="images/<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /storage/ssd5/567/5083567/public_html/test.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/storage/ssd5/567/5083567/public_html/test.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />`


You were correct about that php though, seeing it after several hours of sleep and it does look inredibly ropey

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo $images[0]->filename; ?>" style="width:100%">
<img src="/images/<?php echo $images[1]->filename; ?>" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: Oh, like @tanner-babcock said `$images[0]["filename"]`(I was a little too quick.). Also just `$images[0]`works.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with `<?=$images[0]->filename?>`